# Gtk# - Proper way to clear ActiveText on a ComboBoxEntry?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I am learning C#/Gtk# by jumping in and creating a monstrosity of an app for my own personal enjoyment/torture. My latest quandary is how to clear the items from a ComboBoxEntry. I did find a way to do it, but it seems kludgy to me.

Here is my test app, I create ComboBoxEntry with text and then click a button to clear it:

[image: Initial application load]

Then when I click the button to clear it, the items are removed but "foo" still remains as the active text:

[image: Application with the combo cleared but still has that pesky foo in there]

Anyhow, I figured out a way to clear it with the following code. It seems that there should be a better way to do this but I can't find one so I'm coming here for a sanity check:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{   
    ListStore comboModel1 = new ListStore (typeof(string)); 

    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();

        ComboBoxEntry1.Model = comboModel1; 
        comboModel1.AppendValues ("foo");

        // Set "foo" as selected item
        Gtk.TreeIter iter;
        ComboBoxEntry1.Model.IterNthChild (out iter, 0);
        ComboBoxEntry1.SetActiveIter (iter);
    }

    protected void Button1OnClicked (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Just doing this  .Clear () still leaves "foo" as the ActiveText
        comboModel1.Clear ();

        // My kludge to clear ActiveText
        comboModel1.AppendValues ("");

        Gtk.TreeIter iter;
        ComboBoxEntry1.Model.IterNthChild (out iter, 0);
        ComboBoxEntry1.SetActiveIter (iter);

        comboModel1.Clear ();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it on MacOs 10.7 and a simple comboModel1.Clear() does the trick. There is not ActiveText and furthermore the Combobox isnt event accessible anymore cause there are no values present in the ListStore.
So maybe this is a bug on Windows. But i doubt it and will test in on Windows too.
Just as a hint instead of using IterNthChild you can use GetIterFirst.

Comment: Sry you are talking about ComboboxEntry. I can confirm the same behaviour. So sry for te confusion.